# Convert string to an array of strings on the fly

Tags: c#, arrays, string

I have a method that returns an array of strings. In that method I am processing only one string, and I want to return it as an array of strings (an array of strings with only one element, which is my string → `array[0] == myString`).

I want that because I want to avoid some ugly code for creating an array of strings with one element, like that:

```
private static string[] FooterContent()
{
      string[] array = new string[1];
      array[0] = GetMyData();
      return array;        
}
```

I want something like that:

```
private static string[] FooterContent()
{
      string myData = GetMyData();
      return myData.ToArray();        
}
```

And that `myData.ToArray()` should create an array with only one element (`array[0] = myString`) and then to return it.

Or, something like that (if possible):

```
private static string[] FooterContent()
{
     return GetMyData().ToArray();        
}
```

The point is that I can't simply modify the return type from `string[]` to `string` because I am using the value returned from `FooterContent` (array of strings) and from other similar methods, like `BodyContent` or `HeadContent`, into another general method, `WriteContent()` that accepts an array of strings.

Is there an elegant way of doing this?

Thank you respectfully.

Comment: What is `GetMyData` and what does that return?

Comment: GetMyData returns a string

Comment: Why not just have that return an array? or better yet, an object?

Comment: why not just do `new [] { yourstringhere } ` then?

Comment: If I am doing this, I will face the same problem in GetMyData method. This is not a solution.

Comment: @w0lf: it might be a solution

Comment: This sounds like an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)... What is it you are trying to achieve? Without knowledge of what `GetMyData` is doing its hard to give an answer..

Comment: @Sayse: I really don't think so. The task of "Creating a single element array in the most readable way" is pretty clear one, I think.

Comment: @JonSkeet - Wrapping a single string in an array just seems to create more work for the op since they will then need to unpack it again at the other end (judging from the method name). Creating for an entirely pointless operation

Comment: @Sayse: There are any number of places where that sort of thing makes sense, in my experience - where you want to reuse a method which *sometimes* consumes arrays with more elements. I really don't think there's a need to analyse the overall architecture in order to answer this question.

Comment: @IoniţăCosmin Check my answer, maybe you get surprised ;) Even when you've already choosen a right answer, I still believe that mine should work better in your scenario rather than an extension method.

Comment: @JonSkeet - I agree there are places but I don't think a one line method to turn a string into a 1 item array is the place for that (unless the op plans to override this class of course). I guess will just wait for the follow up question :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As w0lf suggested in comments, the simplest way of creating an array would just be:

```
return new[] { GetMyData() };
```

While you *could* create an extension method, I personally wouldn't - and if you do, you absolutely should *not* call it `ToArray`, as that already has a meaning for `string` due to `Enumerable.ToArray` and the fact that `string` implements `IEnumerable<char>`.

If you really, really want to create this extension method, I'd do it as:

```
public static T[] ToSingleElementArray(this T value)
{
    return new[] { value };
}
```

Then you can use:

```
return GetMyData().ToSingleElementArray();
```

But as I said, I wouldn't even create the extension method...

Answer (score 4):

You can:

```
private static string[] FooterContent()
{
    return new[] { GetMyData() };        
}
```

or write extension method which **isn't the best approach** here (but possible):

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static string[] ToSingleElementArray(this string inputString)
    {
        return new[] { inputString };
    }
}

private static string[] FooterContent()
{
    return GetMyData().ToSingleElementArray();        
}
```

Comment: Calling it `ToArray` is a bad idea IMO, due to the collision with `Enumerable.ToArray`.

Comment: Correct! `ToArray` isn't proper name here - let's change it to something you suggested

Answer (score 3):

Try this,

```
private static string[] FooterContent()
{
     return new[] { GetMyData() };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can wrap your `GetData` return value in a `struct` and use implicit operators to perform conversions:

```
public struct DataResult
{
    private string _raw;
    private string[] _rawArray;

    public DataResult(string raw)
    {
        _raw = raw;
        _rawArray = new [] { raw };
    }

    private string Raw { get { return _raw; } }
    private string[] RawArray { get { return _rawArray; } }

    public static implicit operator string(DataResult result)
    {
        return result.Raw;  
    }

    public static implicit operator DataResult(string rawResult)
    {
        return new DataResult(rawResult);
    }

     public static implicit operator string[](DataResult result)
     {
         return result.RawArray;
     }

    public static implicit operator DataResult(string[] rawResultArray)
    {
        if(rawResultArray == null || rawResultArray.Length != 1)
            throw new ArgumentException("Raw result must be a single item array", "rawResultArray");

        return new DataResult(rawResultArray[0]);
    }
}
```

Implicit operators let you do implicit conversions from apples to pears (and viceversa):

```
DataResult result = new DataResult("hello world");
string[] resultArray = result;
string rawResult = result;

DataResult result2 = new string[] { "hello world" };
DataResult result3 = "hello world";
```

What does it mean? If your `GetData` method returns `DataResult` any other code can set its value to a `string`, `string[]` or `DataResult`, and perform the opposite conversions implicitly.

I believe that in your case, this should be one of best approaches.

Comment: Seems like a world of pain to me in terms of readability - and the fact that the struct is *mutable* is even nastier, IMO.

Comment: @JonSkeet well, I can turn it to *immutable*

Comment: @JonSkeet BTW there's always a discussion about readibility about implicit operators... Sometimes is a good solution. For example, `StackExchange.Redis` does it extensively and I wouldn't argue that it reduces readability in your code. And in my own code I use implicit operators. Right, my #1 choice are extension methods or other approaches, but tools are still there to be used in edge cases

Comment: Oh I agree that *sometimes* they're appropriate - I just don't think this is one of those times. (Nor would I bother with the struct at all, but that's a different matter.)